# Erro ao usar distribuição Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, grails

Estou iniciando no mundo Groovy junto com Grails. Ao rodar o comando 'dbm-update' (para atualizar com bd em minha máquina e as migration etc) ocorre este erro de compilação.

Sei quase nada de java. ( apenas preparar o ambiente, e olhe lá).

Observação importante: rodei um projeto grails do zero, roda tranquilamente.(sem integração com bd)
Já este, o qual clonei do gitlab para trabalhar...dá este erro.
Agradeço dês de já pela ajuda!

```
ommand execution error: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 194: unexpected token: << @ line 194, column 1.
   <<<<<<< HEAD
   ^

1 error


> Task :dbmUpdate FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dbmUpdate'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.292.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug  option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 46m 27s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
| Error Command [dbm-update] error: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution   
 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip'. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Comment: Bem vindo! 
Sempre que postar coloque código escrito (copie e cole com a marcação de markdown - na edição aparece como fazer).
Poste o conteúdo do Spring1.groovy, o erro parece estar nele.

Comment: Oi Leandro. OK, obrigado . Desculpe . :)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo erro me parece mais um problema com um merge git.
Faça `git status` para ter mais informações e depois dê uma olhada no arquivo `Script1.groovy` para ver se não tem balisas que indicam um merge em andamento, como `<<<<<<< HEAD` por exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado amigo. verdade, resolvi isso já. Essa parte do erro...já foi resolvida. Os demais, persistem.